# JPA generate partial unique key

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with 3 columns

1. `UUID` - A UUID that is the primary key of the table
2. `ID` - A human readable ID of the resource (for a new resource, the ID should be automatically generated by a sequence)
3. `Version` - A version number

I am using JPA.

The table can contain multiple records with the same "human readable" ID and different versions.
I would like to be able to insert a new record without specifying the ID: the database should generate the ID automatically.

At the same time, when I need to insert a new version of the same resource, I would like to be able to insert a new row specifying the ID.

I have created a table where the UUID is the primary key, ID is defined as "integer generated by default as identity" and version is just an integer.

Using SQL query I can do what I want, but I do not know how to do it using JPA.

If I define the column as:

`@Column(name="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)`

I can insert new records but the ID is always generated as new even if the resource already has one because the insert does not include the column.

If I define the column as:

`@Column(name="ID", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)`

The insert include the column and I am able to insert new rows specifying the ID but I cannot insert a row without the ID because the SQL generated is passing a `null` value for that column.

**UPDATE**
I have modified the configuration adding the annotation @Generated:

```
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name="ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

With this, I am having the same problem: if I pass a value for id, the database is still generating a new one.

Comment: You will need to generate and pass the ID always. Your use case sounds like auditing requirement, may be [envers](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) helps you

Comment: @Rohit envers seems interesting. Do you know what happens when the definition of the entity is modified? If for example in a later release a column is added, do we need some kind of migration for the audit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `@DynamicInsert` [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value).

Assuming that you have the following table:

```sql
create table TST_MY_DATA
(
   dt_id uuid,
   dt_auto_id integer generated by default as identity,
   dt_version integer,
   
   primary key(dt_id)
);
```

Appropriate entity will look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TST_MY_DATA")
@DynamicInsert
public class TestData
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "dt_id")
   private UUID id;

   // Unfortunately you cannot use @Generated annotation here,
   // otherwise this column will be always absent in hibernate generated insert query
   // @Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   @Column(name = "dt_auto_id")
   private Long humanReadableId;

   @Version
   @Column(name = "dt_version")
   private Long version;
   
   // getters/setters
}
```

and then you can persist entities:

```java
TestData test1 = new TestData();
session.persist(test1);
      
TestData test2 = new TestData();
test2.setHumanReadableId(27L);
session.persist(test2);

session.flush();

// here test1.getHumanReadableId() is null

/*
 *  You can use session.refresh(entity) only after session.flush() otherwise you will have:
 *  org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: 
 *  [this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database#ff09c202-cd17-4d4a-baea-057e475fabb9] 
 **/
session.refresh(test1);

// here you can use the test1.getHumanReadableId() value fetched from DB
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that I have to manually write the ID. How can I generate it? If I have to generate the ID, in which use case would the annotation @DynamicInsert be useful? It will never happen that the ID is null.

Comment: If you do not set `getHumanReadableId()` the ID will be generated by database, because of the `@DynamicInsert` usage this field will be omited in the generated insert query. But for fetching it back to application you should do `session.flush()` and then `session.refresh(test1)`

Comment: That's great! Thank you